# Behind a Reverse Proxy, Spring Security Login Redirects to Wrong Port

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have the following configuration:

- A spring-security enabled web application with form-based login

  - this runs on http port 8080; no https
- A reverse proxy running in front

  - this runs on port 443 and does SSL termination here
  - the proxy sets appropriate headers (`Host`, `X-Forwarded-Proto`)

The issue I'm encountering is that after a successful login, the redirect url that Spring Security builds is `https://server:8443/whatever`.  The url is correct (it's built off of the initial saved request) except for the port.  There is nothing running on port 8443 in this configuration.

I see that this is happening in Spring's `PortMapperImpl`.  There are two mappings by default here: `8080 -> 8443` and `80 -> 443`.

How do I override `PortMapperImpl` or implement my own and force Spring to use that?  Or is there a different way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.  In Spring Java configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int serverPort;

    @Value("${security.sslRedirectPort}")
    private int sslRedirectPort;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.[the usual request matchers, authorizeRequests, etc]
            .and()
            .requestCache().requestCache(requestCache());

    }

    private PortMapper portMapper() {
        PortMapperImpl portMapper = new PortMapperImpl();
        Map<String, String> mappings = Maps.newHashMap();
        mappings.put(Integer.toString(serverPort), Integer.toString(sslRedirectPort));
        portMapper.setPortMappings(mappings);
        return portMapper;
    }

    private RequestCache requestCache() {
        HttpSessionRequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
        PortResolverImpl portResolver = new PortResolverImpl();
        portResolver.setPortMapper(portMapper());
        requestCache.setPortResolver(portResolver);
        return requestCache;
    }

}
```

What's happening here:

- I'm using the existing `server.port` setting to inject the http port (by default this is 8080 in spring)
- I'm creating a setting called `security.sslRedirectPort`.  Set this property to whatever you want it to redirect to in your `application.yaml` file.
- I create a custom `RequestCache` and insert it into the spring security configuration.  In this custom RequestCache, I set the `PortResolver` and on it, the `PortMapper`, and then set the mapping values accordingly.

Now when I run, I get a correct redirect url after logging in, with the port set to whatever I set `security.sslRedirectPort` to.